# I cannot see the dblog of my kickstart commerce

Tags: routes, commerce, log-messages

When I navigate to `/admin/reports/dblog`, nothing happens. It only shows me a node, and if I go to the Admin menu then I cannot see the reports link. Check the image below to better illustrate my issue:

[image]

**My questions**: Why I cannot see the reports menu? And how can I access the dblog info?

Comment: Is the "Database logging" module enabled? I would guess not...

Comment: I found a module called syslog is that one that you are talking about?

Comment: Nope, it's called "Database logging"; the machine name is `dblog`. It's a core module

Comment: yes it is enabled check the image http://clip2net.com/s/iihQYg
any other reason?

Comment: None that I can think of, except rogue cache entries or a misbehaving module. Try [rebuilding the menus](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/58618/how-do-i-call-the-menu-rebuild-function-in-drupal-7/82222#82222) as a next step

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found in the Commerce kickstart documentation that the dblog is disabled by default due to this functionality consumes a lot of resources.

Enable database logging module and then rebuilt the menus as suggested by Clive