# View leads to 'Page not found'

Tags: views, uri

I had created a page called Analysis and then created a view with exactly the same name and /path. Did I confuse Drupal? I then deleted the Analysis page to have only a view at that path but am getting a page not found whenever I visit the link even though preview is showing the right thing.

Comment: [How do I call the menu_rebuild function in Drupal 7?](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/58618/how-do-i-call-the-menu-rebuild-function-in-drupal-7/82222#82222)