# When does hook_menu run?

Tags: 7, hooks, routes

I need to edit the hook_menu function in my  module.  I need to add a new link to a menu, and edit the path for an existing link.  Is this possible without creating a whole new module?

The only example in the docs for when hook_menu runs is when the module is enabled.  Is there any other time it runs?

Comment: `hook_menu()`, together `hook_menu_alter()`, is invoked when menu definitions needs to be rebuild, which normally happens when any module is installed, removed, enabled, or disabled. The question is a little unclear, though. What do you mean by _I need to edit the hook_menu() function in my module_? Disable the module, edit the code, and re-enable the module.

Comment: @kiamlaluno Editing the code doesn't require disabling the module. If you edit the hook implementation, the menu will not show any updates. That is probably why the OP is asking. How do you rebuild the menu after editing a module's hook_menu()

Comment: @mbomb007 Editing the code of a module doesn't tell Drupal that the menu definitions need to be rebuild. Drupal doesn't check the last time a module file has been changed, so it will not know the `hook_menu()` implementation has been possibly changed.

Comment: When a module is disabled, enabled, uninstalled, or installed, Drupal will rebuild the menu definitions. To do that, it will need to invoke every `hook_menu()` and `hook_menu_alter()` implementations. That is why disabling a module works.

Comment: It doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 1):

Clearing the cache the menu and routing tables will be reconstructed.

In the admin UI, go to:

`/admin/config/development/performance`

Using drush:

```
drush cache-clear all
```

Other methods are described here: [How do I call the menu_rebuild function in Drupal 7](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/58618/how-do-i-call-the-menu-rebuild-function-in-drupal-7/82222#82222)?